Permanent EBS for ECS container instance
I’m trying to mount an EBS volume which persists even if task restarts (will be used by a self managed database engine). So I know adding it to task managed by service won’t work since it destroys my EBS on restarts.
Then I attached the EBS on my Launch Template (with deleteOnTerminate=false) which is used by the ASG on ECS container instances (ec2). AFAIK I can’t have more than 1 instance on my ASG, let me explain why, If I set desired to 2 on ASG it might launch 2 EC2 on same AZ, and each instance will have its own EBS, so even with az placement constraint I can’t guarantee to my task always use the correct ebs.
So my final solution will be use max 1 instances on ASG but I’m thinking if it’s the best solution at all.
Any suggestions here folks ?
SOLUTION
I created an AWS EBS and after an AWS ASG with min=1,max=1 scale configurations. On the user_data script, I mounted this AWS EBS in my node and it works fine. I think it's a workaround but it works , I didn't find a better approach without using AWS ECS.

This is one of the reasons why running a database on ECS is generally a bad idea. What type of database engine are you running? Will RDS not work?

it’s a mysql , don’t want to use rds for some internal reasons
